# unable to handle wso2 ESB with Activemq

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, esb, wso2-esb

In my project We are trying to configure activemq with wso2 esb.
Successfully configured and we are getting successful responses for first 4 or 5 requests. After that getting socket timed out error.

Can anyone know this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better if you can provide more detail on the interaction between ESB and activemq, what type of operation you are doing, also show the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Can you describe how you have connected WS02 to ActiveMQ?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the activeMQ socket time out configuration using transport.soTimeout property. This property can be configured as java.naming.provider.url in your axis2.xml of ESB.

eg: tcp://localhost:61616?transport.trace=false&transport.soTimeout=60000

Please refer [1] for more TCP transport options

[1] http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html